# Data pager in icefaces not paging

Tags: icefaces

I have been trying to populate data from a csv file in ice:datatable. I am trying to bind the datatable to a data paginator to display 10 rows on each page.But when I click on other page numbers of paginator,it encounters the following exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -10
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setFirst(UIData.java:275)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.datapaginator.DataPaginator.broadcast(DataPaginator.java:160)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Adding the  that I am using.

```
<ice:dataTable id="csvDataTable" 
        value="#{fileControllerBean.rowModel}" 
                               rows="10">

<ice:columns value="#{fileControllerBean.columnModel}"
                                 var="headings">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{headings}"></h:outputText>               
</f:facet>        
                                                <ice:outputText value="#{fileControllerBean.cellValue}">                        </ice:outputText>

</ice:columns>
                                                /ice:dataTable>

<ice-cc:dataPager forTable="csvDataTable"></ice-cc:dataPager>
```

Comment: I cannot see the problem from the stack trace.  Can you please add the <ice:dataPaginator> and <ice:dataTable> components from your web page to the problem description.

Comment: @Simon C : Added the components I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but this error usually happens when in any of the setters called when the page is changed, the `dataTable` model changes, for example if a `clear()` is called.